# nginx: Install vimbadmin in to subfolder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I tried to install vimbadmin in to subfolder, but i can't. No matter what configuration i use, vimbadmin never work. This is my last configuration

```
# vimbadmin
location /vimbadmin {
    alias /usr/share/vimbadmin/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/vimbadmin/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico))$ {
        alias /usr/share/vimbadmin/public/$1;
    }
}
```

but nginx return me Error: 403 -

> *14 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 90.154.205.85, server:
>   mail.devx.biz, request: "GET /vimbadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mail.example.com"

I could not imagine how hard it is.[Here](https://github.com/opensolutions/ViMbAdmin/wiki/Installation#nginx) is original nginx confiration whick work perfectly on domain/subdomain.

Can you help me with some advices, or example configuration for do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my last and worked nginx configuration

```
location ^~ /vimbadmin {
    alias /usr/share/vimbadmin/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @vimbadmin;
    location ~* \.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}

location @vimbadmin {
    rewrite ^/vimbadmin/(.*)$ /vimbadmin/index.php?$1 last;
}
```